# How warm should SAMSUNG D3 drive be?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, temperature

I have an external 3GB Samsung D3 Station 7200rpm hard drive and my SMART diagnostics program (CrystalDiskInfo or HDSentinel) is warning me that the drive is running too hot.

The temperature in the room is usually about 20C. My problem is that with copying operations (1, or 2 hours), the internal drive temperature rises too high (almost 50). Is it normal? thanks

Comment: No, it's not normal for you to receive alerts that your drive is overheating.

Comment: I know, but I heard that drive manufacturers are intentionally designing drives to run hotter so they can sell more drives that latest hard drives reach higher and higher temperatures , is it true? thanks

Comment: No, that's not true.

Comment: If you haven't already, clean the dust out of your computer, and ensure it is getting proper airflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I could not find details for your specific drive, this temperature would seem to be within the normal operating parameters for a hard disk (albeit on the high side - but then again you are running it for long periods, and presumeably without airflow moving across the drive).

According to [this article](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/193771en) the operating range for Seagate hard drives is up to 60 degrees for the newer drives (50 degrees for the older ones).  On the flip side, running your drive at higher temperature could lead to a higher failure rate (but is still acceptable, just)- see [here](http://www.buildcomputers.net/hdd-temperature.html).    This is relevant as it appears the D3 Station is actually made by Seagate.

Based on a [comment on NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822152408), it wold appear these drives do run hot due to poor ventilation, and putting a fan across it will help dramatically.

Comment: so, as I understand, there's no defect present from manufacturing in my hdd. Thanks for your exhaustive answer bro!

Answer (score 2):

I have 2x D3 3TB. Internally it is ST3000DM001 drive. The cappiest drive on market, rated for only 2300 hours yearly. My drive resulted sector relocation and bad sector errors at 129 hours of running (1.5 year old, rare in usage, always packed in original box while out of use). Today I bought second D3 3TB, to make clone of first one.

After 2 hours both reached 60 degrees, but older one reached 64 degrees celsius. I stopped cloning process. Than I have 3x Seagate expansion, which reached 76 degrees celsius once. Than I stacked 3 in a tower and put back a 12V/12CM fan. They run ok after 2 years now. Seagates run very hot. Externals have barely some wenting holes.

It's sad, that we must make external cooling for drive, nut to die after few months and that we must make backups of backups, because drives are so low quality these days.

While 64 degrees once in a lifetime of a drive is nothing to worry, but bad sectors are.